# webpack, merging files, then passing merged file to entrypoint

Tags: webpack, merge

I'm Struggling with webpack. To fix some cyclic dependencies, I was told to merge the interdependant files into one .js file instead of using "import" between them. So to make my life easier at first, I thought of merging all the files, and then put "entry" to point to the merged file.
So I've put a MergeIntoSingleFilePlugin into exports.plugins.
It seems that the plugin is run last, because the "entry" doesn't find the merged file on the first run. Anyway, I'm new to webpack, things are confusing.

I'm also confused about the purpose of module.exports... can I run things before module.exports? Should I call a javascript function to merge files outside of the module.exports statement ??

const path = require('path');
const MergeIntoSingleFilePlugin = require('webpack-merge-and-include-globally');

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './merged.js',

  plugins: [
     new MergeIntoSingleFilePlugin({
        files: {
          "./merged.js": [

              ... list of files,
          ],
      }
  })
 ]

};
```